Getting "Can't find Symbol" on SequenceStyleGenerator during migration from spring boot 2 to 3
I'm upgrading to spring 3.0 and java 17 from 8 and one issue I'm encountering is that
final String defaultSequenceName = ConfigurationHelper
            .getBoolean(SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY, params, false)
                    ? params.getProperty(JPA_ENTITY_NAME) + sequencePerEntitySuffix
                    : SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_NAME;

SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY and SequenceStyleGenerator.DEF_SEQUENCE_NAME are deprecated and I'm just not sure how to replace it. Is there anything else I can use? Thank you!

have you checked it's documentation?

@Stultuske I can't able to find suitable thing to replace can you help me in it.

if there is something to replace it, it's likely in the documentation

@Stultuske yes that's the issue I can't locate the exact thing to replace it in the documentation
